# domain of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}\right)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Determine the domain of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}\right)^n$$

Let , $$a_n=\left(\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}\right)^n$$

Then , $$\lim_n |a_n|^{1/n}=\left|\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}\right|$$

Now $\sum a_n$ is convergent if $$\left|\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}\right|<1\implies \left|\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}\right|^2<1$$

$$\implies (1-e^z)(1-e^{\bar z})<(1+e^z)(1+e^{\bar z})$$

$$\implies e^z+e^{\bar z}>0\implies e^x(e^{2iy}+1)>0\implies y>\pi/2$$

So, the required domain of convergence $\{z=x+iy\in \mathbb C:y>\pi/2\}$.

> Are my process and answer correct ?

Comment: Process good. Answer is not. You end up with an inequality that is in terms of imagnary numbers and that do not make sense. Note that it should be $e^x(e^{iy} + e^{-iy}) = 2e^x\cos(y) > 0$ and not $e^x(e^{2iy }+1) > 0$ so it seem like you just made a minor mistake in the last inequality.

Comment: Yes..I had confusion about that inequality. So I post this...

Comment: So, $\cos y>0$. So the domain will be $\{z\in \mathbb C:y<\pi/2\}$. Is it?

Comment: Not quite. First of all $\cos(y)$ is $2\pi$ periodic in $y$ so after finding all valid values in $[0,2\pi]$ the rest are those $+2\pi k$ for any integer $k$. Secondly there are more values in $[0,2\pi]$ where $\cos(y)$ is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $\cos(y) > 0 \to -\dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi  < x < \dfrac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi \to D = \{x+iy: x \in \mathbb{R} , -\dfrac{\pi}{2} +2n\pi < y < \dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi \}$.

Answer (score 2):

We need $|1-e^z|<|1+e^z|$

If $z=a+ib,$   $$(1-e^a\cos b)^2+(e^a\sin b)^2<(1+e^a\cos b)^2+(e^a\sin b)^2$$

$\iff e^a\cos b>0$

As $e^a>0$ for real finite $a$ $e^a\cos b>0\iff\cos b>0$

$\iff2m\pi-\dfrac\pi2< b<2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2$ where $m$ is any integer